# Ruby function to calculate average search time for a skip list

Tags: ruby, skip-lists

I'm trying to write a ruby function to determine the average expected search time for a skip list. I don't have a strong math background and I believe the results I'm getting from this function are not correct.

`n` = number of elements in the list

`base` = denominator of the promotion probability. i.e. if 1 of 4 nodes are promoted base = 4

```
def lookup_eficiency(n, base)
  return (Math.log(n, base)*(base/2.0))
end
```

How do I express an equation in Ruby which will take the number of elements in a skip-list and a base and return the average search time?

Comment: So what? What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was implied but I just edited the question to make it explicit.

Comment: If you want to measure the speed of the function, you can use  the module `Benchmark` http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html . Does that answer part of your question?

Comment: Not exactly. I want to use this function to calculate the expected number of operations for a theoretical skip-list. I'm writing the skip-list itself in C. I want to be able to determine the theoretical search time for skip-lists with a varying number of nodes and varying probabilities of node promotion (i.e. 1/2 nodes promoted vs. 1/4, 1/8, etc.).

Comment: But I don't know of many people who search for theoretical data! Better to get a profile-representative set of terms that you expect to actually turn up and run some nearly-real tests against that. (This matters because there are quite often functions that do better than expected when working with real data, or even worse than expected.)

Comment: That's a valid point however, I would still like to know how to mathematically express the expected average search time. I'm trying to graph things out so I can get a sense of how the size of the list and promotion probability relate to the average search time. I know that I shouldn't expect these relations to absolutely hold true when applied but I do think it will give me a general indication of tradeoffs involved. In particular, I'm interested in safely decreasing the promotion probability in order to save memory (since the "bottom list" is simply a linked-list with a single pointer).

Answer (score 0):

Since complexity of a skip list look up is O(logbase(n/base)), how about this ?

```
def lookup_efficiency(n, base)
  Math.log(n/base)/Math.log(base)
end
```

Make sure your base is a float so you don't end up with integer division !

Comment: Why not just call `base.to_f`?  It'll be a no-op if you already have a float.

Comment: You're actually right. I just thought not to clutter the code with more than the basic functionality the OP required and mention it instead.

Comment: Thank you but I when I test your function, I get results that seem wrong. For instance, for a skip-list with 1000 elements and a promotion probability of 1/10 (`n = 1000` and `base = 10`), the function returns `2.0`. If `base = 20` the function returns `1.306...`. I believe this is incorrect since in any list where `n > base`, a search operation would, on average, require visiting approximately `base/2` nodes on the "bottom list" alone.

Comment: My bad, seems like I mistook the search look up time with the space needed to store the list. According to [this](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/PLDS210/niemann/s_skl.htm) the worse case is O(n) and the best case is O(log n). It's a pretty wide range and you can't be sure which calculation is the more accurate ( Although I suspect it to tend toward O(log n) the more levels you add .. ). I suggest calculating best and worst case and making your decision upon both.